# How to Set up AWS java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i am trying to run simple AWS project in Eclipse but not able to do that. I am very new with this. I have already followed all the step given in official site don,t know what i am missing. please if anyone who has already done this guide me.
Thanks a ton....

Sample Code:

https://github.com/naohta/java_hello_dynamodb

Guidlines: 
http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/faqs/#What_is_the_AWS_Toolkit_for_Eclipse &

```
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3586?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1
```

Comment: Please provide more info what you have tried what is your problem etc

Comment: @a paul i just simply want to run AWS project on Eclipse and for that i already have sample source code. I am even not able to create AWS java Project but able to create AWS java Web project.

Comment: Did you installed "AWS Toolkit for Eclipse" ?

Comment: @APaul ya i installed..after that what i need to do..

Answer (score 0):

Moving to answer from comment.

I will suggest below steps

1. AWS Toolkit for Eclipse
2. This is a good tutorial, might help you. http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1GZLJAE4RCX4J/Eclipse-New-AWS-Java-Project-Wizard

Comment: @a paul I want to create New AWS java project but i am not able to do this. according to given tutorial I am trying to do...

Comment: Great. Go ahead I am sure you will be able to do that. Let us know if you have any specific question. And if the above answer help you dont forget to mark it as answer :)

Comment: @a paul still same problem i am not able to create New AWS java Project... :-(

Comment: I think some issues with your eclipse. Please download the latest eclipse and try. It should be very easy to config, not sure what is the issue.